# How to random char (+\*-) in c?

Tags: c

I have been asked to create code that displays to the user two random numbers and a random mathematical arithmetic operation between them.

I know how to make a random number in C:

```c
int a=(rand()%100)+1;//Random number 1-100
```

But I'm unsure on how exactly to create a random character. I know that you can use ASCII to create a random character.

Comment: Do not spam languages tags. Tag only the language you are actually using.

Comment: Create an array of 4 characters. Then create a random index within this array, as you know how to do it.

Comment: All three of those languages are incredibly different. Also, this is not a code writing service. Clearly state what you are trying to do, what language it is in, where you are having a specific compile time or runtime error or issue, and the minimal but complete code to demonstrate that.

Comment: `int rand_char = "+/*-"[rand() % 4];`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to choose a character randomly is probably to just put the appropriate characters in an array/string, and select one of them:

```cpp
char const operations[] = "+-/*";

char op = operations[rand() % (sizeof(operations) - 1)];
```